# How to store key-value data in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, multi-model-database

ArangoDB is known to support not only graph and document model, but also key-value model. So my question is: how to store simple key-value data?

I read that it could be a problem in ArangoDB: [Issue on Github](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/663)

Comment: What issue are you running into? Key-value is effectively the same as a Document with no additional indexes aside from primary.

Answer (score 2):

Simple key-value data in ArangoDB is stored as a document collection without additional indexes.

> The key/value store data model is the easiest to scale. In ArangoDB, this is implemented in the sense that a document collection always has a primary key _key attribute and in the absence of further secondary indexes the document collection behaves like a simple key/value store.

This is listed in the [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Scalability/DataModels.html#keyvalue-pairs).